# JavaFX binding confusion

Tags: java, scala, javafx

I am using an abstract class that I am not allowed to change.

The abstract class has this operation: `saveButton.disableProperty().bind(validBooleanProperty.not())`.

In my subclass I have `@FXML private var titleTextField: TextField = _`, which is a `TextField` that contains the title of the project.

I would like to make it so that when the `titleTextField` gets any sort of input, the `saveButton` reacts to it. I have attempted to create a listener for the `titleTextField.textProperty()` however I get `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'addListener'` error. I have no idea why it does that.

How can I bind / listen to changes in the `titleTextField` and make the `saveButton` react in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what confused me here, the answer is pretty simple:

```
saveButton.disableProperty().bind(titleTextField.textProperty().isEqualTo(""))
```